# Time Series - Is there increasing variance?

Tags: r, time-series, variance, stationarity

I can't figure out if this time plot has increasing variance or not. From my initial guess of the time plot, I would say no but I've taken the difference and it looks like variance is increasing slightly. I've subsequently taken a log transformation and differenced that also where the variance looks to be constant. I'm just wondering is the data variance increasing so much that a log transformation needs to be taken in order to start making the series stationary? I've attached all plots below.
[image: Time Plot], [image: Difference plot], [image: Difference of log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My eye tells me (marginally!) yes, but I would prefer actually testing for non-constant error variance via the TSAY test discussed here http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html . Note that  the error variance can change at different points in time AS COMPARED to the error variance being proportional to the expected value as is discussed here [When (and why) should you take the log of a distribution (of numbers)?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-to-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers) .

Note well that untreated anomalies can often incorrectly guide the erroneous conclusion that variability of the error process is non-constant which is why Box and Jenkins incorrectly transformed/logged the Airline series. See a discussion here https://autobox.com/cms/index.php/blog and https://autobox.com/pdfs/vegas_ibf_09a.pdf illustrating the spurious correlarion between error variance and the expected value caused by a few anomalies in the most recent year.

Actually post your original observations and I will be more analytical/objective in my assessment of "constant error variance" .

Comment: It is in fact airline passengers that I am reviewing. I'll have to take a look into the TSAY test as I've never heard of it, I'm still quite new to this subject. I have seen in a lot of examples that the log is taken but the increase in variance is often more pronounced. In my dataset I don't see any outliers later on that would cause the increase in variance.

Comment: perhaps there are none ,,,,but that doesn't imply that there are no deterministic change points in error variance at one or more points in time. I definitely see more time series that have deterministic change points in error variance than those needing a power transform. AUTOBOX which I have helped to develop tests for both in it's tour de force.

Comment: By the way my on-board computer suggests via my eyes that the error variance breakpoint is about at the end of 2013 or so. Why are you studying/examining the airline series ?

Comment: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0047287505279003 Chris Chatfield was not too complimentary about using logs for the airline series ... Kudos to my friend and mentor Chris C.